# Installed Ubuntu on separate partition and now can't boot into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Windows 7 computer. I Installed on a separate partition, all my files are still in that partition, but now I am getting the Ubuntu boot loader  and it does not give me the option to boot into Windows. How can I get back to Windows.

Here is a image of my Grub:
[image]

As you can see in the picture, grub has Windows 8 while in fact I have Windows 7, which is installed on my `/dev/sda2` partition (in the grub the thing that says "Windows 8 recovery environment"). If anyone could give me a little more information and even if possible the code I would have to use I would greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the GRUB. That's the thing that will allow you to choose Ubuntu or Windows at startup.

I think you should start by looking at the [GRUB documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) and look specifically to section "Configuring GRUB 2". It will show you how to set default behavior and a lot of cool thing to custom.

But be careful, you can do a lot of damage with the wrong modification.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer if it worked ;)

Comment: Thanks NorTicus what you said would have most likely worked but I ended up doing a fix mrb in Windows recovery. For anyone else with this problem I would recommend doing this, the only problem is you will not be able to boot into Ubuntu. Here is a guide on how to do fix mbr https://www.youtube.com/watchv=kFU8kngy6O0 If you do want a Ubuntu just do a reinstall but properly configured and if you don't just delete the Ubuntu partition and restore it to windows.